# Possible ways to Sort records which uses non English fonts?

Tags: php, sorting

I m using Devnagari fonts in my application. Each English key in keyboard represent certain character in Devnagari. For example my name is Sabin in English but when i use devnagari font it would be ";lag" without quotes. And records are saved in this way in the database. Now i m having problem in sorting records.

In devnagari first comes are Devnagari vowels and then devnagari alphabets. Like
c,cf,O,O{,p,pm,...... [each one separated by comma]
Then devnagari alphabets equivalent starting from first,
s,v,u,#,... and so on [each one separated by comma].

Problem I m having is sorting names alphabetically in devnagari. Any idea will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: The array returned as following which I need to use usort function.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => NLK32437
        [first_name] => ;lag
        [last_name] => %]qL
        [email_address] => test1@msn.com
        [mobile_number] => 9834874582
        [description] => g]kfn
        [date_joined] => 08-AUG-12
        [status] => 1
        [username] => user1
        [userpassword] => 691f9298642af07c2d6ea8fef56074201e077b34
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => NLK32435
        [first_name] => clgn
        [last_name] => zdf{
        [email_address] => test2@msn.com
        [mobile_number] => 984134354
        [description] => g]kfn
        [date_joined] => 08-AUG-12
        [status] => 1
        [username] => user2
        [userpassword] => 0e025eade868b4b481f41ff7449bc1967261e170
    )

)
```

Comment: Sort where? In a PHP array? Your Database/SQL?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is implementing your own comparator function and then writing a bubble sort...

Comment: Have you set the correct [locale](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) ? PHP supports a lot of languages. Though I don't know whether it supports Devnagari (honestly don't even know where that is spoken ;))

Comment: @madflow Well i already specified they are stored in database, database would be Oracle.

Comment: @SabinChhetri You tagged your question "PHP". With PHP you have only limited multibyte support.

Comment: @madflow Oh, stop the FUD, please.

Comment: @madflow, so that means there is no possible way to do that, as php and database recognizes "A" as the first letter, not "c" or "S" ?

Comment: @SabinChhetri The database will not (at least not without you modifying it's code). For PHP you could write a custom sorting function or just find one on the internet that accepts a comparator function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are abusing text encodings. You are saving your text as codepoints that are meant for other things, and are only using a font that renders the originally English letters as something else. This is entirely the wrong way to go about it.

There are several encodings which let you save Devanagari as actual Devanagari characters. It's [supported in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devnagari#Devan.C4.81gar.C4.AB_in_Unicode). Save the text as actual Devanagari characters that they were meant to be, don't overload existing English code points and depend on a broken font. Then you'll get sorting functionality and many other things by anything that supports Unicode.

---

A simple `usort` example nonetheless:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    static $order = array('M', 'A', ';', 'L', ...);
    return array_search($a, $order) - array_search($b, $order);
});
```

Comment: well, i have thought that too, i m rewriting old application built some decade ago with other programming language, using oracle as a database. I have to migrate those millions of data to the new application, and they've done that way. I have to make data stored consistent.

Comment: Then your first step should be to migrate the data over to proper Unicode code points. Then your other problems will solve themselves.

Comment: Thanks deceze!. There are millions of records, and I m not allowed to change or alter any of their existing data. In this scenerio what would be the best option left for me?

Comment: I suppose you want to sort in the database as well, not just in PHP, so this is a really bad basis to build on. You can `usort` in PHP (figure it out, lots of examples), but that won't help you for the database.

Comment: I assumed you (@SabinChhetri) just mixed up what a font and what a character is, I'm sorry for that. And of course this solution is certainly the way to go.

Comment: @SabinChhetri duplicate the database. Altering would not be a good idea anyway since it would break current code, right?

Comment: @deceze, unfortunately i have to sort it in database and show it in PHP.

Comment: @dualed, yes i know i m doomed, but I didnt do that, i m just starting rewriting the existing application but in PHP, They've stored data that way in the database in their old application.

Comment: I think the better option will be fetch the record from database as it comes, store it in an array, then make a function to use it in usort, Sort this array and display the result

Comment: @SabinChhetri is the database still maintained / being changed?

Comment: @dualed, yes they'll use existing system unless the new application is completed and debugged. After then the data migration from old database will be done.

Comment: You might want to experiment with views and stored procedures so that you can do things on the fly w/o actually changing data in the database. So you can try before you change data or can provide some legacy mode or whatever. Nowadays we have a lot of possibilities, be flexible, dynamic thinking helps to solve problems

Comment: @SabinChhetri ok then I would take the current database, duplicate/migrate it, work out a process for safe and quick migration, develop the app on the new, sane, database, and when done make a switch. I don't know how long migration will take, but you will find out when doing the initial one. Afterwards you can backup and take down the old database. Together with that custom font.

Comment: @deceze, I m trying to figure out using usort  function but not being able to do so. I could do say for example if values are to be sorted so that values beginning with letter "M" comes first. But I have problem here for example how do i sort array so that value starting with M comes first, then starting with K comes second, then starting with P comes third and then starting with O comes fourth and so on.?

Comment: @deceze, I m having trouble using the code you specified. I have array returned in the given format [please see my original post, i have edited it]. The array is returned by codeigniter query. 
I need to sort by first_name so that "clgn" comes first and then ";lag"
How I m suppose to use your code on this scenerio? I will be pretty much grateful Thanks!

Comment: @Sabin Please create a new question for your new question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well i just got it working, after a try. Thanks @deceze and @dualed.
Here is what i did

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    static $order = array('c', ';', 'g', 'L');
    return array_search($a->first_name, $order) - array_search($b->first_name, $order);
});
```