# Using usort to sort multidimensional array on the basis of certain condition

Tags: php, arrays, usort

This question is followed up question from ['This question'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825097/possible-ways-to-sort-records-which-uses-non-english-fonts). The codeigniter code returns the database recordset as following array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => NLK32439
        [first_name] => sdn
        [last_name] => hf]zL
        [email_address] => user1@hotmail.com
        [mobile_number] => 9841349349
        [description] => g]kfn
        [date_joined] => 09-AUG-12
        [status] => 1
        [username] => user1
        [userpassword] => 691f9298642af07c2d6ea8fef56074201e077b34
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => NLK94358
        [first_name] => alag
        [last_name] => k|wfg
        [email_address] => user2@gmail.com
        [mobile_number] => 823472384723
        [description] => g]kfn
        [date_joined] => 09-AUG-12
        [status] => 1
        [username] => user2
        [userpassword] => 691f9298642af07c2d6ea8fef56074201e077b34
    )

    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => NLK32437
        [first_name] => ;lag
        [last_name] => %]qL
        [email_address] => user3@msn.com
        [mobile_number] => 9851112412
        [description] => g]kfn
        [date_joined] => 08-AUG-12
        [status] => 1
        [username] => user3
        [userpassword] => 691f9298642af07c2d6ea8fef56074201e077b34
    )

    [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [user_id] => NLK32435
        [first_name] => clgn
        [last_name] => zdf{
        [email_address] => user4@msn.com
        [mobile_number] => 984134354
        [description] => g]kfn
        [date_joined] => 08-AUG-12
        [status] => 1
        [username] => user4
        [userpassword] => 0e025eade868b4b481f41ff7449bc1967261e170
    )

)
```

All i want to do is sort array by "first_name" on the basis of certain condition. My php code so far is-

```
<?php
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    static $order = array('c', 's','a',';', 'L');
    return array_search($a->first_name, $order) - array_search($b->first_name, $order);
});
?>
```

My intention to do is sorting the array so that the first_name begining with 'c' comes first, with 's' comes second, with 'a' comes third and with ';' comes fourth.

But above code is not working as expected. It is returning the records in the sequence :

```
's','a',';','c'
```

it should return in the sequence

```
'c', 's','a',';'
```

I m using custom Devnagari font, so each albhabet in keyboard represent certain character in devnagari. So in devnagari, c comes first, s second and so on.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because using array_search will only return when the string is completely match some string in the array.

```
$array = array('a','b','c');
var_dump(array_search('blue',$array))
// This will output
bool(false)
```

So, if you want you can try this :

```
<?php
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
static $order = array('c', 's','a',';', 'L');
return array_search(substr($a->first_name,0,1), $order) - array_search(substr($b->first_name,0,1), $order);
});
?>
```

Hope this helps.

UPDATE : for your question on your comment, I have an idea. Please take alook.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    //example for the orders
    static $orders = array (';l', 'c', 's', 'a', ';', 'L');

    //variables to count the point for $a and $b (it is equal at first)
    $pointA = 1;
    $pointB = 1;

    //also variables to mark if $a or $b are matched on one of the orders
    $isFoundA = false;
    $isFoundB = false;

    //iterate foreach orders
    $i = 0; //this is something to add to the point, the more earlier the first_name found in the order, the less point will be added
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        //if $a->first_name is still not found in orders and it has been just founded 
        if (!$isFoundA && strpos($a->first_name,$order) === 0) {
            $pointA += $i;
            $isFoundA = true; //we don't need to check this again since we had found it
        }
        //if $b->first_name is still not found in orders and it has been just founded 
        if (!isFoundB && strpos($b->first_name,$order) === 0) {
            $pointB += $i;
            $isFoundB = true; //the same as above, we don't need to check it again
        }
        $i++;
    }
    //after iterate in orders, we check the points for $a and $b
    if ($pointA == $pointB) return 0;
    else return ($pointA < $pointB) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Now the order has no limitation on characters. You can specify something like `static $orders = array('abc','a',';');` or `static $orders = array('abcdef', 'b', 'z', ';', 'c[');` Please let me know if it works on you.

Comment: Yes i already figured out that, thanks for the reply. But ran into another problem. Sometimes two alphabets represent one character in Devnagari, like s] represent one character in devnagari. Is there anyway to maintain that for example if we have the $order array like this, and i want to check against first character and first two characters then what would be the possible solution?

static $order = array('c', 's','s]','a',';', 'L');

Comment: Thanks a lot for code, but the code is not seeming to work as expected. What I have is 

static $orders = array('c', 's',"s'",'a',';', 'L');

Result should be in the same order as above array, but its displaying in a sequence "c","a","s'",";","s"